# Redmi 6 - can't hang up phone

Tags: android

I want to implement the function of hanging up the phone.

But in Redmi 6 (Android 8.1), it has not been possible.

I used the following two methods：

1.

```
TelecomManager telecomManager = (TelecomManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE);
if (telecomManager != null) {
     telecomManager.endCall();
}
```

Get the following error：

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10179 nor current process has android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE
```

2.

```
TelephonyManager mTelMgr = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Service.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
Class<TelephonyManager> c = TelephonyManager.class;
try {
    Method getITelephonyMethod = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony", (Class[]) null);
    getITelephonyMethod.setAccessible(true);
    ITelephony iTelephony;
    iTelephony = (ITelephony) getITelephonyMethod.invoke(mTelMgr, (Object[]) null);
    iTelephony.endCall();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Get the following error：

```
java.lang.SecurityException: MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permission required.
```

But in other mobile phone tests, it can be executed.

I don't know where the problem is.

Comment: i think MODIFY_PHONE_STATE can only be granted on rooted devices

Comment: hidden APIs like ITelephony change often, not documented and are not uniform across devices

Comment: @yasuo Thanks for your answer, I know that MODIFY_PHONE_STATE is a system privilege. I am looking for a way to hang up without using this privilege. I am using the Notification actionIntent of Notification to implement this function.

Answer (score 1):

From [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#MODIFY_PHONE_STATE)

MODIFY_PHONE_STATE
added in API level 1

public static final String MODIFY_PHONE_STATE

Allows modification of the telephony state - power on, mmi, etc. Does not include placing calls.

> Not for use by third-party applications.

so your app cannot use this permission unless its system app or your device is rooted

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know that MODIFY_PHONE_STATE is a system privilege. I am looking for a way to hang up without using this privilege. I am using the Notification actionIntent of Notification to implement this function.